# Maximum Number of Packages That Can Be Installed

Tags: managed-package, package-install

Is there a maximum number of managed packages that can be installed in a single org or is it unlimited as long as the org stays under the other limits for objects, apps, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such limit on number of Managed packages installed (Assumes its approved Managed package listed on AppExchange). However you need to mindful of total custom object limits for the Edition,  CPU transaction limits (for this test the apps together in a sandbox) and other limits.

From the limits [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.overview_limits_general.htm&type=5)

> The custom objects that are contained in a managed package that’s publicly posted on AppExchange don’t count against the allocations for your Salesforce edition. At the same time, an org can’t have more than 3,000 custom objects, regardless of the source or namespace of those objects. For example, in Unlimited Edition: 2,000 custom objects created, 1,000 custom objects installed by packages. Soft-deleted custom objects and their data count against your limits. We recommend that you hard delete or erase custom objects you no longer need.

Answer (score 2):

There is no documented hard limit on the number of packages you can install in an org. There are a number of limitations that can block installation, such as exceeding the custom object hard limit or the custom field per object hard limit. There are also a number of post-install problems that could occur, such as the 10 namespace per transaction limit, CPU timeout exceptions, long-running concurrent transaction limits, and more. In other words, depending on which combination of packages you install, you could start hitting limits with just 5 or 10 packages, or if planned out, you could conceptually have hundreds or thousands of installed apps in an org without any problems. The usual advice here is to always install in Sandboxes beforehand, and test thoroughly before going to production, since the installer may not catch runtime problems.